# Stanford NLP Server "Could not handle incoming annotation" in German

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to use Stanford NLP server with German text. I tested http://corenlp.run/ and it works fine in German. If I try it on my own machine 
using

> java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
>   [port] [timeout]

it just works in English. If I select German I get the error message

> Could not handle incoming annotation

the command line shows:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)     at
>   java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)   at
>   java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)    at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.getProperties(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:681)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:540)
>     at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)     at
>   sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)    at
>   com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)  at
>   sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
>     at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)     at
>   sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I guess I have to add the German .jar file somewhere, but I can't find how and where?

Answer (score 0):

ok i unzipped the german .jar file and used the properties file in there, which locks like this.

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, ner, parse

tokenize.language = de

pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger

ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.conll.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz
ner.applyNumericClassifiers = false
ner.useSUTime = false

parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz

# depparse
depparse.model    = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz
depparse.language = german
```

i started the server like this

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -props StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties
```

but still german is not working.

i cannot find what to do with the "*". i also tried to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <classifier>models-german</classifier>
</dependency>
```

to the pom.xml

Comment: By the way 3.7.0 is not currently in Maven so adding it to the pom.xml won't work.

Answer (score 0):

3.7.0 is currently in beta mode.

So make sure to re-download the latest copy of 3.7.0.

If you start the server with this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

NOTE:  You will need all of the jars in

```
stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/*
```

and

```
stanford-german-corenlp-models-current.jar
```

in your CLASSPATH for this command to work.  There were some path issues in the German jar, so also re-download it as I just fixed it now.

Issue your request with this command:

```
wget --post-data '<insert German text here...>' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner,parse","pipelineLanguage":"de","outputFormat":"json"}' -O -
```

And it should work fine!

NOTE: To put the jars in your CLASSPATH you can issue this command:

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/*:/path/to/stanford-german-corenlp-models-current.jar
```

(replace /path/to with wherever those resources are on your machine)

or when you call java you can specify a CLASSPATH, like so:

```
java -cp "/path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/*:/path/to/stanford-german-corenlp-models-current.jar" ...
```

The server looks at the "pipelineLanguage" property in the request to load the German properties, so using "-prop" with edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer won't work.